# Does JSONP work with jquery 1.4

Tags: jquery, jsonp

I have this code :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#search_input").autocomplete({
      source: function(request, response) {
        $.ajax({
          url: 'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql',
          dataType: 'JSONP',
          data: {
            format: 'json',
            q: 'select * from xml where url="http://google.com/complete/search?hl=nl&output=toolbar&q=' + encodeURIComponent(request.term) + '"'
          },
          success: function(data) {
            response($.map(data.query.results.toplevel.CompleteSuggestion, function(item) {
              return { label: item.suggestion.data, value: item.suggestion.data };
            }));
          }
        });
      }
    });

    });
```

For some reason it doesn't work with Jquery 1.4 but it does with 1.7 Is this becouse JSONP was not introduced with 1.4? How can I make it work with 1.4?
Here is the Fiddle [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TnPRA/)

Comment: If you look in jQuuery's 1.4.1 [source code](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.1.js), you can see that JSONP is present. Also, your fiddle seems to work here. What exactely "does not work" for you?

Comment: The problem is that I want to change this: `<script class="jsbin" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` Into this `<script class="jsbin" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` But when I do it doesn't work anymore so I was wondering why that is.

Comment: I suspect it has something to do with the jquery ui which is handling the drop down list, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/TnPRA/2/

You've got two problems:

1. Wrong usage of JSFiddle.

   - You included the resources at the upperleft section, while loading Mootools.
     The correct usage is to select `jQuery ____` at Use `Choose framework`,
   - You also added the script to the HTML and script section (= running the same code twice).
2. The critical part of your code is caused by jQuery itself:
   In jQuery 1.4, the response is a string. To get the code to work in older jQuery versions, add one line to the `success` handler:

   ```
   success: function(data) {
     if (typeof data == 'string') data = $.parseJSON(data);
   ```

Comment: Thanks, I could have never figured this out:)

Comment: Well, at first, I fixed the JSFiddle set-up. Then, when the problem persisted, I added `alert(data);` right after `success: function(data) {` (because of the `ReferenceError`). I saw a plain string, and drew my conclusions. *(basic debugging steps)*